# AJAX Sends data to PHP file, but PHP can't get data from $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am making a page on a website in PHP where a user fills out 3 fields and hits submit. The submit button should call my AJAX function to send the data to a database connection PHP file. I can confirm the data is sent from AJAX (via an alert) and the function returns a Success. This must mean my database query file is not interpreting the data correctly. Please help me understand where I went wrong.

Code from php page where the form is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function storeInvoice() {
    //var c_name = document.getElementById('c_name');
    //var c_license = document.getElementById('c_license');                         
    //var c_licenseemail = document.getElementById('c_licenseemail');
    var data=$('#myForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
        url: "/paydb.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        async:false,
        dataType:'html',
        success: function (value) {
            alert("Sent: "+data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Relevant Code from Database php file:

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, "main_db" );

$c_license = $_POST['c_license'];
$c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
$c_licenseemail = $_POST['c_licenseemail'];

//Another method was attempted below.
//$data=$_POST['serialize'];
//$c_licenseemail = $data['c_licenseemail'];
//$c_license = $data['c_license'];
//$c_name = $data['c_name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `invoices`(`company`, `licensenum`, `licenseemail`) VALUES ('$c_name','$c_license','$c_licenseemail');";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

The data is sent as:

```
c_name=testname&c_license=3&c_licenseemail=testemail%40email.com
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: He is using the POST method in his AJAX call @dan08

Comment: @dan08 serialize makes the data sent in this way, he can still retrieve the data with $_POST vars

Comment: I saw `dataType: 'html'` in an example I was referencing.

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Can you print `$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");` in php file & paste the output

Comment: @AgamBanga It seems normal, Sent: c_name=testname&c_license=3&c_licenseemail=testemail

Comment: @NathanBrown Can you try this

`mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` & see if it gives you any error.

Comment: @AgamBanga This seems useful, ERROR: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I have added the answer. Please check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

For duplicate key, you need to make the primary key to auto increment in your database.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Seems to be working as intended now.

Comment: Glad, i could help.

Answer (score 1):

In your success callback function replace `alert(data)` with `alert(value)` and in your `database.php` file echo any of the post variables to just check whether the values are correctly sent to `database.php` via ajax post.

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: The echos have the correct value. For example echo "c_license" sends back 3 if 3 was typed into that field.

Comment: It's wierd, it sent the query to the DB after making these small changes only. But it only worked twice and now no longer works. I'm confused..